# how to write a ERC1155 smartcontract to sell nft?

Tags: web3js, remix, ether, smart-contract-wallets, erc-1155

I trying to write a ERC1155 smart contract, where you can sell the nft for someone for a certain eth or wei, and receive that eth or wei in my address. help me with some examples. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In the ERC1155 standart we have `_mint()` function which is internal. What you need to do is write a `mint()` function that requires a amount of token being sent to the contract (don't forget to add a withdrawn function there!) to a new token to be minted to the `msg.sender`.